# vertical scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html

i want to create a scroll bar in my project . I have a table which have two row and two column. In first column of first row( width 25%) i want to put a scroll bar .  I need the customizes scroll bar. not the overflow style method ..

Is any idea ?

Comment: What kind of custom behavior do you want? (How should it differ from the built-in scroll bar?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add div to that cell with `overflow:scroll` style rule